# django search returns a blank page

Tags: django, search, django-views

I have designed my search box in my django app but the search only returns the extended html page, not the search results.
#View

```
class SearchListProject(ListView):
paginate_by = 4
template_name = 'website/search_project.html'

def get_queryset(self):
    search_project = self.request.GET.get('q')
    return Project.objects.filter(description__icontains=search_project)

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['search_project'] = self.request.GET.get('q')
    return context
```

#url

```
    path('search_project/', SearchListProject.as_view(), name='search_project'),
path('search_project/page/<int:page>', SearchListProject.as_view(), name='search_project')
```

#html

```
{% extends 'website/project_list.html' %}

<h3 class="alert alert-primary text-center">Search: {{ search_project }}</h3>
{% block previous_page_url %}
    {% url 'website:search_project' page_obj.previous_page_number %}?q={{ search_project }}
{% endblock %}
{% block next_page_url %}
    {% url 'website:search_project' page_obj.next_page_number%}?q={{ search_project }}
{% endblock %}
```

#my form

```
                <form action="{% url 'website:search_project' %}">
              <input type="text" name="q">
              <button type="submit"><i class="icofont-search"></i></button>
            </form>
```

Comment: I can see you write the `h3` tag outside of any block. That won't work as you are extending a template. Any content **must** be put inside a block.

Comment: Yes, but that is not the problem in here

Comment: I don't see you trying to display the search results anywhere. the part of the template you show only has this header which will not be rendered. If this is your complete template of course your results won't be rendered as you don't render them. If not you should show the part of your template where you render your results.